# Viewing DOM source using Chrome Developer Tools

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

I am unable to figure out how I can view the DOM source for the following web page, using Chrome Developer Tools:

https://www.nseindia.com/corporates/corporateHome.html?id=eqFinResults

I am interested in scraping the entries from the table on the page (i.e. the table with column names **Symbol, Company, .... , XBRL Filename, Status**).

I tried various options, including:

1. View page Source
2. View Frame Source
3. Highlighting a row in the table and selecting **Inspect**
4. Highlighting the entire page (Ctrl+A) and selecting **Inspect**

Answer (score 0):

In DevTools, click the arrow icon
[image],
then click on the element (Symbol etc).

You will see its source selected inside DevTools.
You may right-click and copy it.

For Symbol, this will look like:

```
<div class="x-grid3-hd-inner x-grid3-hd-Company" unselectable="on" style="" id="ext-gen119">Symbol<img class="x-grid3-sort-icon" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAID/AMDAwAAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw=="></div>
```

However, this won't help you much, since you then need to copy the CSS code,
which is a much more complicated operation.